# SQLite : requesting from a table filled via a trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite, if I have have a table `bar` that is updated via a trigger when I do an `INSERT` on `foo`, will `SELECT` requests on `bar` wait until all triggers have executed? For example, if my trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo_bar AFTER INSERT ON fo 
  BEGIN
    UPDATE bar SET bar.val = new.val WHERE bar.id = new.id;
  END;
```

and I send a request:

```
INSERT foo.id, foo.val VALUES (0, 1);
```

And then I send the request:

```
SELECT bar.id, bar.val FROM bar;
```

will all triggers fired because of the trigger `foo_bar` be executed before the `SELECT` request is treated, or is the `SELECT` request treated asynchronously?

Comment: The trigger will not fire because neither the UPDATE nor the INSERT use valid SQL syntax. ☺

Comment: Sorry - the example code was pseudo-code to elaborate the idea. The answer below is exactly what I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers are always executed synchronously with the triggering statement.
(Otherwise, it would not be possible to use the [RAISE() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#undef_before) to abort the statement.